# How do I find out w/YUM or RPM what files it installed?

Tags: linux, fedora, rpm, yum

I installed Fedora 16 last night and saw it had NoMachine's NX in the repo.  I did a

```
yum install nx
```

and it says it installed correctly, but for the life of me I can't find the **.service** or **/etc/init.d** file(s) or even the **/etc** configuration files for any sort of NX server.  I do see

```
nxssh
nxproxy
nxagent
```

but there aren't even **man** entries for them.

To be able to figure out what it's done, what I'd like to do is see exactly **what** files and **where** it put them.

I've looked and looked-- is there a command I can invoke, either **yum** or **rpm** that tells me the files contained in an already-installed RPM?  Something like how

```
rpm -qpl <some rpm>.rpm
```

lists the files (with directories) packaged in an RPM.

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the --filesbypkg argument for rpm.

```
rpm -qi --filesbypkg nx
```

Comment: Yay! I can comment now! I'm glad to help :)

Comment: @Wildcard it's a subargument to `-q`, explained in the `query-options` part of the manpage. `-i` is `--info`, and means: "Display package information, including name, version, and description. This uses the --queryformat if one was specified."

Answer (score 1):

The `yum-util` [`repoquery`](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/RepoQuery.html) lists installed files, e.g.,

```
repoquery --list nx
```